# Mapping a field using existing target value (Mapstruct)

Tags: mapstruct

i have a custom case that some of my dto's have a field of type X, and i need to map this class to Y by using a spring service method call(i do a transactional db operation and return an instance of Y). But in this scenario i need to use existing value of Y field. Let me explain it by example.

```java
// DTO
public class AnnualLeaveRequest {
    private FileInfoDTO annualLeaveFile;
}
```

```java
//ENTITY
public class AnnualLeave  {

    @OneToOne
    private FileReference annualLeaveFile;
}
```

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class FileMapper {
    @Autowired
    private FileReferenceService fileReferenceService;

    public FileReference toFileReference(@MappingTarget FileReference fileReference, FileInfoDTO fileInfoDTO) {
        return fileReferenceService.updateFile(fileInfoDTO, fileReference);
    }
}
```

```java
//ACTUAL ENTITY MAPPER
@Mapper(uses = {FileMapper.class})
public interface AnnualLeaveMapper {
    void updateEntity(@MappingTarget AnnualLeave entity, AnnualLeaveRequest dto);
}
```

```java
// WHAT IM TRYING TO ACHIEVE
@Component
public class MazeretIzinMapperImpl implements tr.gov.hmb.ikys.personel.izinbilgisi.mazeretizin.mapper.MazeretIzinMapper {

    @Autowired
    private FileMapper fileMapper;

    @Override
    public void updateEntity(AnnualLeave entity, AnnualLeaveUpdateRequest dto) {
        entity.setAnnualLeaveFile(fileMapper.toFileReference(dto.getAnnualLeaveFile(), entity.getAnnualLeaveFile()));
    }
}
```

But mapstruct ignores the result of "FileReference toFileReference(@MappingTarget FileReference fileReference, FileInfoDTO fileInfoDTO) " and does not map the result of it to the actual entity's FileReference field. Do you have any idea for resolving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

## Question

How do I replace the annualLeaveFile property while updating the AnnualLeave entity?

## Answer

You can use `expression` to get this result. For example:

```
    @Autowired
    FileMapper fileMapper;

    @Mapping( target = "annualLeaveFile", expression = "java(fileMapper.toFileReference(entity.getAnnualLeaveFile(), dto.getAnnualLeaveFile()))" )
    abstract void updateEntity(@MappingTarget AnnualLeave entity, AnnualLeaveRequest dto);
```

MapStruct does not support this without expression usage. See the end of the `Old analysis` for why.

### Alternative without expression

Instead of fixing it in the location where `FileMapper` is used, we fix it inside the `FileMapper` itself.

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class FileMapper {
    @Autowired
    private FileReferenceService fileReferenceService;

    public void toFileReference(@MappingTarget FileReference fileReference, FileInfoDTO fileInfoDTO) {
        FileReference wanted =  fileReferenceService.updateFile(fileInfoDTO, fileReference);
        updateFileReference(fileReference, wanted);
    }

    // used to copy the content of the service one to the mapstruct one.
    abstract void updateFileReference(@MappingTarget FileReference fileReferenceTarget, FileReference fileReferenceFromService);
}
```

## Old analysis

The following is what I notice:

1. **(Optional)** your FileMapper class is not a MapStruct mapper. This can just be a normal class annotated with @Component, since it does not have any unimplemented abstract methods. (Does not affect code generation of the `MazeretIzinMapper` implementation)
2. **(Optional, since you have this project wide configured)** you do not have `componentModel="spring"` in your `@Mapper` definition, maybe you have this configured project wide, but that is not mentioned. (required for the `@Autowired` annotation, and `@Component` on implementations)
3. Without changing anything I already get a working result as you want it to be, but for non-update methods (not listed in your question, but was visible on the gitter page where you also requested help) the `FileMapper` as is will not be used. It requires an additional method that takes only 1 argument: `public FileReference toFileReference(FileInfoDTO fileInfoDTO)`
4. (Edit) to get rid of the else statement with null value handling you can add `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE` to the `@Mapper` annotation.

I've run a test and with `1.5.0.Beta2` and `1.4.2.Final` I get the following result with the thereafter listed `FileMapper` and `MazeretIzinMapper` classes.

## Generated mapper implementation

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-03-11T18:01:30+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 1.4.50.v20210914-1429, environment: Java 17.0.1 (Azul Systems, Inc.)"
)
@Component
public class MazeretIzinMapperImpl implements MazeretIzinMapper {

    @Autowired
    private FileMapper fileMapper;

    @Override
    public AnnualLeave toEntity(AnnualLeaveRequest dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AnnualLeave annualLeave = new AnnualLeave();

        annualLeave.setAnnualLeaveFile( fileMapper.toFileReference( dto.getAnnualLeaveFile() ) );

        return annualLeave;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateEntity(AnnualLeave entity, AnnualLeaveRequest dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( dto.getAnnualLeaveFile() != null ) {
            if ( entity.getAnnualLeaveFile() == null ) {
                entity.setAnnualLeaveFile( new FileReference() );
            }
            fileMapper.toFileReference( entity.getAnnualLeaveFile(), dto.getAnnualLeaveFile() );
        }
    }
}
```

## Source classes

### Mapper

```java
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring", uses = { FileMapper.class }, nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE )
public interface MazeretIzinMapper {

    AnnualLeave toEntity(AnnualLeaveRequest dto);

    void updateEntity(@MappingTarget AnnualLeave entity, AnnualLeaveRequest dto);
}
```

### FileMapper component

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class FileMapper {
    @Autowired
    private FileReferenceService fileReferenceService;

    public FileReference toFileReference(@MappingTarget FileReference fileReference, FileInfoDTO fileInfoDTO) {
        return fileReferenceService.updateFile( fileInfoDTO, fileReference );
    }

    public FileReference toFileReference(FileInfoDTO fileInfoDTO) {
        return toFileReference( new FileReference(), fileInfoDTO );
    }
    
    // other abstract methods for MapStruct mapper generation.
}
```

## Why the exact wanted code will not be generated

When generating the mapping code MapStruct will use the most generic way to do this.
An update mapper has the following criteria:

1. The `@MappingTarget` annotated argument will always be updated.
2. It is allowed to have no return type.
   the generic way to update a field is then as follows:

```java
// check if source has the value.
if (source.getProperty() != null) {
  // Since it is allowed to have a void method for update mappings the following steps are needed:
  // check if the property exists in the target.
  if (target.getProperty() == null) {
    // if it does not have the value then create it.
    target.setProperty( new TypeOfProperty() );
  }
  // now we know that target has the property so we can call the update method. 
  propertyUpdateMappingMethod( target.getProperty(), source.getProperty() );
  // The arguments will match the order as specified in the other update method. in this case the @MappingTarget annotated argument is the first one.
} else {
  // default behavior is to set the target property to null, you can influence this with nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.
  target.setProperty( null );
}
```

Comment: What im trying to achieve is generating an updateEntity method which will look like: @Override
    public void updateEntity(AnnualLeave entity, AnnualLeaveRequest dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return;
        }
            
         entity.setAnnualLeaveFile( fileMapper.toFileReference( entity.getAnnualLeaveFile(), dto.getAnnualLeaveFile() ) );
        }
    }

Comment: 1. FileMapper is a MapStruct Mapper abstract class. I also have some extra abstract methods which are off topic. 2. Yes componentModel="spring" is configured on project level.

Comment: ahhh now I finally understand what you want. You want to replace the `annualLeaveFile` property, while you do update the `AnnualLeave` entity. MapStruct currently attempts to update the `annualLeaveFile` property, which I read as expected behavior.
So your question is: "how do I replace the `annualLeaveFile` property while updating the `AnnualLeave` entity?". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes thats what i exactly need

Comment: added a way to get this result to the top of the answer.

Comment: thank you for the time and effort you spend on this, that's a clever way using an expression there. i have not tried it yet but it seems like a proper solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that has not resolved the issue. on FileMapper class i dont know which entity/dto has the FileReference/FileInfoDTO fields and their field names. So i need more generic solution. Which is probably can not be achieved using mapstruct.

Comment: Problem is I dont want to add an extra line on each Entity/Dto mapper. It might be forgotten by development team and cause bugs

Comment: I can think of one more option to do this. Not sure how well it will work for you, because I do not know if there are any immutable fields in the FileReference/FileInfoDTO classes. Updating the post to add it.